# Create a textfield and send button at the bottom of uitableview like Instagram comment section

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I would like to add a textfield and send button that sticks to the bottom of uitableview. I added a footer to the tableview to achieve this, but it seems like the footer is appearing right under the last comment instead of the very bottom of uitableview. I'd also want to move the footer up when the keyboard appears and down when it is dismissed. Below you can see my code for reference. Thanks!

[image: Expected Result i.e. instagram/chat app textfield at bottom]

`Expected Result`

[image: Actual outcome]

`Actual outcome`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    footer = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44))
    footer!.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    textField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(5, 5, 315, 35))
    textField!.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Bezel

    yourSendButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(318,5,62,35))
       // [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225,5,75,35)];
    yourSendButton!.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    yourSendButton!.setTitle("Send", forState: .Normal)
    yourSendButton!.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGrayColor(), forState: .Normal)
    yourSendButton!.addTarget(self, action: "sendBtnClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    //addTarget:self action:@selector(sendBtnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    footer!.addSubview(yourSendButton!)
    footer!.addSubview(textField!)

    self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(footer!)

    return footer
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}

func sendBtnClicked (sender: UIButton) {
    print("send button pressed")
    print(textField?.text)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a  tableView in custom UIViewController this code can help you :

```
    var commentField:UITableViewCell!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"keyboardWillAppear:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"keyboardWillDisappear:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func keyboardWillAppear(notification: NSNotification){

    var userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize:CGSize = userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)!.CGRectValue().size

    var contentInsets:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)

    self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    var messageFrame:CGRect = self.commentField.frame
    messageFrame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
    self.commentField.frame = messageFrame

}

func keyboardWillDisappear(notification: NSNotification){
    var userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize:CGSize = userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)!.CGRectValue().size

    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.25)
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    UIView.commitAnimations()

    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero

    var messageFrame:CGRect = self.commentField.frame
    messageFrame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
    self.commentField.frame = messageFrame
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you'd add a tableview inside a viewcontroller. It looks like a tableview cell would be the comment field, but where would I add a textfield and send button? Thanks.

Comment: You need just to add uitableview to your viewcontroller then add the cell that contains the comment and under your uitableview put a textfield and a send button since you can modify your uitableview heigh and width with storyboard and dont forget to implement tableview datasource , hope it hep :) if my answer helped dont hesitate to verify my answer :) thanks